# how can i exclude the virtual drives from the drives array

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I got a string of all drivers i got in my computer then i got their types to exclude the CD drives but i want to remove the virtual drives as i return the real CD drive and the virtual drives ( as flash memory, USB ...)?

Comment: Could you post some code to show what you're currently doing?

Comment: Possibly using GetLogicalDrives and converting the bit mask into a list of letters followed by GetDriveType?  There's a comment at the bottom of the MSDN Artical http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364939%28v=vs.85%29.aspx on getting the BusType of a drive, I realise it's not in Delphi but it shouldn't be too difficult to convert.  Maybe that will help you split out the different drive types.

Comment: James, the Bus type does not indicate if the drive is virtual or not.

Comment: You would probably also want to recognize SUBST drives (we can have a virtual drive P: pointing to C:\MyDir\MySubDir for example), and MAPPED NETWORK drives (virtual drive Z: pointing to \\NetServer\NetShareName\Dir\SubDir). I have seen that this was properly handled in Total Commander, where it's FIND FILES dialog gives you LOCAL HARDDISKS option button, which properly selects just C: and D: in my case, and not the subst or mapped network drives.

Answer (score 2):

Sara, I think which your real question must be , how i can determine when a CD-ROM (or any) drive is a virtual drive? so the answer to this question is: the Virtual Drives works and behaves just like a physical CD/DVD drive, also **there is not any property which identify a Drive as Virtual**, because that as far i know there is not exist any **reliable** method to determine when a drive is virtual. the only approximation as possible solution for you question is create a list of `SCSI`,`IDE` drivers (something like a dictionary) associated to virtual drives (containing strings like *Virtual CloneDrive*) then you can get the associated SCSI or IDE controller associated to the CDROM drive and search in your list of virtual drives controllers to determine if the Drive is virtual or not.

Comment: It would however be possible to identify various specific kinds of virtual drives, such as one made by VirtualCloneDrive.  You would follow the notes JamesB posted in a comment, and either identify bus types, or device drivers that are associated with the "controller" that provides this drive.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will help, but as alternative you can try to test if the drives are ready.  Empty CD's and empty USB devices will return false if not ready.  It is a good way to eliminate not ready drives from your list.

```
function IsDriveReady( const ADrive: string ): boolean;
{ Checks if a local drive is ready. Drive must be a valid local drive (A:\ to Z:\). }
var
  ErrorMode: word; // current error mode
  DriveNum: integer; // zero based number of drive
begin
  Result := False;
  // Get zero based drive number
  DriveNum := GetDriveNumber( ADrive );
  if DriveNum = -1 then
    exit;
  ErrorMode := Windows.SetErrorMode( Windows.SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS );
  try
    // DiskSize requires 1 based drive numbers
    // returns -1 for invalid drives
    if SysUtils.DiskSize( DriveNum + 1 ) <> -1 then
      Result := True;
  finally
    Windows.SetErrorMode( ErrorMode );
  end;
end;
```

Comment: While it's a nice answer, it's not an answer to this question. :) The question was about **virtual** drives, which your code does nothing to identify.

Comment: it's a point that i have to consider Bill Thanks for your help but i was asking to exclude the virtual drives from the array of drivers i got. thanks for ur effort :)